# Consul connect Envoy proxy dynamic port

Tags: amazon-ecs, consul, envoyproxy, servicemesh

We use AWS ECS with bridge network mode, it is the reason why we can't use static 21000 port for sidecar Envoy proxy, because we want to use sidecar Envoy proxy for each service. Unfortunately by some reasons we can't start using awsvpc network mode, so we have to find a way to use a dynamic port for Envoy proxy instead of 21000.
Could someone take us some suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

By default Consul auto-assigns the port used by Envoy from a configurable range; [`sidecar_min_port`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#sidecar_min_port) and [`sidecar_max_port`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#sidecar_max_port).

You can override this and select a specific port by configuring [`sidecar_service.port`](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/registration/sidecar-service#port) in the service registration file. For example:

```json
{
  "service": {
    "name": "web",
    "port": 8080,
    "connect": {
      "sidecar_service": {
        "port": 21200
      }
    }
  }
}
```